# konva, container with vuejs

Tags: vue.js, konvajs, konva

I got the problem, that VueJS refuse me a problem when I use the .
I have to use that element, because otherwise elements are not overlapping themselfes.
Pics:

[ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtRnt.png)

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mqHc.png)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the <v-container> tag. Just simply remove it and it should work.